# Slickgrid: array scheme inconsistent when data exceeds initial row count

Tags: slickgrid

I initialize an editable Slickgrid with n rows. A user keys or pastes >n rows of data. The grid adds rows to hold the extra data, but when I then `grid.getData()` the resulting array has a different format for rows >n. For example, when n=2 it looks like this

```
[["A","I","X"],
 ["B","J","Y"],
 {"0":"C","1":"K","2":"Z"}]
```

I need this array to be uniformly constructed. I tried this but without effect:

```
grid.updateRowCount();
grid.render();
thatdata=grid.getData();
```

Hopefully I'm missing something simple in the docs--any help appreciated!

Edit: I should have mentioned I'm using the Celebio/Nereo labs fork, so this isn't purely a Slickgrid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SlickGrid does not add the data to the array for you.  You do that by subscribing to `onAddNewRow` and providing the implementation to add a new item to the array, so it's your code that adds the data in the wrong format.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to point me in the right direction on this question (and thanks a ton for Slickgrid--it's great). I'm using the Nereo Labs fork so this issue originates in their code. Still, isn't there a way, irrespective of the way the data got to the grid, to collect just the displayed values from the grid into an array?

Comment: The grid doesn't keep it's own internal view of the data - it just reads the data from the data provider it was initialized with as it needs.  The grid.getData() just returns a reference to the very same array in your case.  You'll need to figure out what and where is modifying that array incorrectly.